# Базовая реализация Google Play Billing на Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Имея приложения на Python Kivy, решил попытаться разобраться как реализовать через Google Play платный доступ (одноразовый платеж) к определенным разделам приложения.
Поскольку нигде внятного источника информации не нашел для таких ситуаций и видео на Youtube не помогли, решил пробовать "методом тыка", частично прося подсказки у ChatGPT.

Приложение сначала было протестировано без кода платного доступа (который посоветовал ChatGPT) и работало. После внесения кода, начало материться, что Python не знает модули Google. Поэтому принято решение пробовать тестировать через Google Play Console.

Вот код.

```
from google_play_billing import get_purchases, purchase_product  *#это ChatGPT посоветовал*
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FadeTransition



Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'payedtext'  *#это и есть платный раздел*
                
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press:

                root.manager.current = 'menu'

<PayedScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'YOU PAID'

""")


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PayedScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
        settings_screen = SettingsScreen(name='settings')
        sm.add_widget(menu_screen)
        sm.add_widget(settings_screen)
        payed_screen = PayedScreen(name='payedtext')


        purchases = get_purchases()  *#данный раздел тоже ChatGPT посоветовал*
        if 'myapp.settings_button' in purchases:
            # User has purchased the button, show it
            payed_screen.add_widget(Button(text='My settings button'))
        else:
            # User has not purchased the button, show the purchase button
            purchase_button = Button(text='Purchase settings button')
            purchase_button.bind(on_press=self.purchase_settings_button)
            settings_screen.add_widget(purchase_button)


        sm.add_widget(payed_screen)
        
        return sm


    def purchase_settings_button(self, instance):  *#И это ChatGPT посоветовал*
        # Initiate the purchase flow
        purchase_product('myapp.settings_button', 'inapp')

        # After the purchase is completed, refresh the screen
        self.root.current = 'payedtext'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Базовое создание aab файла через buildozer release прошло нормально. Создание с подписанием файлом .keystore тоже прошло хорошо.

Добавил файл в Google Play Console - никаких ошибок не выдало.

Но при тестировании, после скачивания - приложение сразу вылетает после запуска.

Вопросы.

1. Может кто посоветует источники где можно пошагово изучить реализацию in-app billing для Python Kivy ?
2. Можно ли как-то протестировать приложение до загрузки на Google Play Console, но чтобы сервисы Google при этом сработали и показали всё ли работает ?
3. Как выяснить какие ошибки выкидывают скачанное приложение после запуска, чтобы узнавать как их исправить ?
4. Может кто подскажет как лучше и правильнее текущий код подправить.